# Is microsoft security essentials good enough to secure PC

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

I am running a small business, has group of 10 people. I am planning to install security essentials in all machines, Is this enough to keep PCs protected or Is there any other products from microsoft to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly adequate as your resident scanner. It will catch the big stuff before it bites you.

I would recommend using it in conjunction with a good passive scanner because it doesn't always catch the small stuff. You run the passive scanner on a sechdule, say monthly. The [free version of Malwarebytes](http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html?part=dl-10804572&subj=dl&tag=button), for example, is a good passive scanner.

Comment: +1 for advising to run a 'manual' **spyware** scanner, next to the always-on virus scanner.  Virus scanners are seldom very good at catching spyware and trojans.

Answer (score 0):

Security Essentials is a good program and runs quietly on the background as you will be aware.
The big plus thing is that it is free - when I had a small business importing food into the country we used SE and it did the job fine. We mainly did emails, but the internet was always going.

I do not see a reason why you wouldn't be able to have it set as your AV program of choice. If you set up your router with a good WiFi password it help you along the way.

Good Luck:-)